# How to specify WPF Theme in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, themes, initialization

I found out that I can use a different theme in an C# WPF Application by adding the theme .xaml-file to the project and add

to App.xaml as a Resource. see http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes for a more detailed description.

Can I do this as well at runtime in C#?
Is it possible to specify a different theme for different wpf windows?

Best regards
    Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share themes between applications and have each one use a different one.

I didn't think you could mix themes within the same application, but marc40000 has found out you can:

```
<Button Height="23" Margin="81,65,122,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Button.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary Source="ShinyBlue.xaml"/>
    </Button.Resources>
    Button
</Button>
<Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,38,35" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75">Button</Button>
```

> put the resourcedirectory to the controls you want to theme instead of doing it globaly in the app.xaml

There's even more information from this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx) and [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358533.aspx)

Comment: For completeness: I found out that you can mix themes within the same app like this:

        <Button Height="23" Margin="81,65,122,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Button.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ShinyBlue.xaml"/>
            </Button.Resources>
            Button
        </Button>
        <Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,38,35" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75">Button</Button>
 
put the resourcedirectory to the controls you want to theme instead of doing it globaly in the app.xaml